# Android studio теряет конфигурацию при открытие проекта с нашим вторым проектом

Tags: android-studio

Есть два проекта, основной на котлине и второстепенный , на джаве. Первый проект задается как главный, а второй существует в проекте как либа, хоть и со своим mainActivity и тд(просто залили второй проект к первому без особых изменений). В итоге Android Studio перестает понимать конфигурацию проекта и не может его забилдеть, и красиво разложить по папочкам. Что делать? От настроек ничего не зависит- откатывал до дефолтных и обновлено на максимум. Показывает что нужно добавить конфигурацию, но она уже есть в проекте и у коллег норм открываеться

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно ответить... Без структуры обоих проектов ничего не посоветуешь. Что вы имеете ввиду, говоря "залили второй к первому"?

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий тот который заливался стал либой для основного

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла полная перестановка Android Studio, а также затирание проекта на локальной машине после чего заново загрузил этот проект.